# Python Requests POST to website with verification token

Tags: python, post, token, python-requests, verification

I'm using Python 3.3 and the Requests library to do a basic POST request.

I want to simulate what happens if you manually enter information into the browser from the webpage:
https://www.dspayments.com/FAIRFAX. For example, at that url, enter "x" for the license plate and Virginia as the state. Then the url changes to: https://www.dspayments.com/FAIRFAX/Home/PayOption, and it displays the desired information (I care about the source code of this second webpage).

I looked through the source code of the above two url's. Doing "inspect element" on the text boxes of the first url I found some things that need to be included in the post request: {'Plate':"x", 'PlateStateProv':"VA", "submit":"Search"}.

Then the second website (ending in /PayOption), had the raw html:

```
<form action="/FAIRFAX/Home/PayOption" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="6OBKbiFcSa6tCqU8k75uf00m_byjxANUbacPXgK2evexESNDz_1cwkUpVVePA2czBLYgKvdEK-Oqk4WuyREi9advmDAEkcC2JvfG2VaVBWkvF3O48k74RXqx7IzwWqSB5PzIJ83P7C5EpTE1CwuWM9MGR2mTVMWyFfpzLnDfFpM1" /><div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
```

I then used the name:value pairs from the above html as keys and values in my payload dictionary of the post request. I think the problem is that in the second url, there is the "__RequestVerificationToken" which seems to have a randomly generated value every time.

How can I properly POST to this website? A "correct" answer would be one that produces the same source code on the website ending in "/PayOption" as if you manually enter "x" as the plate number and Virginia as the state and click submit on the first url.

My code is:

```
import requests

url1 = r'https://www.dspayments.com/FAIRFAX'
url2 = r'https://www.dspayments.com/FAIRFAX/Home/PayOption'

s = requests.Session()

#GET request  
r = s.get(url1)
text1 = r.text
startstr = '<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="'
start_ind = text1.find(startstr)+len(startstr)
end_ind = text1.find('"',start_ind)
auth_string = text1[start_ind:end_ind]


#POST request
payload = {'Plate':'x', 'PlateStateProv':'VA',"submit":"Search",
           "__RequestVerificationToken":auth_string,"validation-summary-valid":"true"}

post = s.post(url2, headers=user_agent, data=payload)
source_code = post.text
```

Thanks, -K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need the data from the first page, and as you say, the __RequestVerificationToken changes with each request.

You'll have to do something like:

- GET request to https://www.dspayments.com/FAIRFAX
- harvest __RequestVerificationToken value (Requests Session will take care of any associated cookies)
- POST using the data you scraped from the GET request
- extract whatever you need from the 2nd page

So, just focus on creating a form that's exactly like the one in the first page. Have a stab at it and if you're still struggling I can help dig into the particulars.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it seems like a good idea. I edited my post to have the updated code following your advice. I'm still not getting the source code I would expect and I see "Due to inactivity, your session has timed out" in my returned POST request source_code. Is there something additional I should be doing?

Comment: You'll want to ignore what the url changes to - the important url is the one that the form within the first page POSTs to (https://www.dspayments.com/FAIRFAX). Changing it to `post = s.post(url1, data=payload)` worked for me (I didn't bother supplying the user_agent).

Comment: The trick with this scraping is to imagine it from the web browser point of view. At each step you just have the html / cookies that were sent back to you. What forms are in the page, what can you submit? You need to simulate those actions pretending to be a real user.

Comment: Aidan, thanks for your suggestion, it was successful so I am accepting your answer. I opened up a very similar question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514316/python-requests-get-and-post-to-website-with-verification-token and would be interested to now how to do this for a case where there are multiple sequential pages btwn. the first and final pages? Essentially, I tried collecting all the name/value pairs in the first and intermediate pages and then doing a POST request.