# Python Requests GET and POST to website with verification token

Tags: python, post, get, token, python-requests

I'm using Python 3.3 and the Requests library to do a basic POST request.

I want to simulate what happens if you manually enter information into the browser from the webpage: https://capp.arlingtonva.us/tap/AC_xwTapPay.aspx. For example, try entering "2. Parking Tickets", clicking next, entering 1234 as the plate number and Virginia as the state and clicking next, and then checking the checkbox and clicking next.

Although the url is the same, there are multiple iterations of inputting information and clicking next.

Currently, I am doing a GET on the url to get the randomly generated strings like the values for "__EVENTVALIDATION" and "__VIEWSTATE" in the source code. Then I do a POST with that information as well as some other information.

Am I using the right post payload as below in my code?

My code is:

```
import requests
url = r'https://capp.arlingtonva.us/tap/AC_xwTapPay.aspx'

#GET request
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url)
text1 = r.text

#getting "__EVENTVALIDATION" value:
eventvalstartstring = r'id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="'
eventvalstart = text1.find(eventvalstartstring)+len(eventvalstartstring)
end_ind = text1.find('"',eventvalstart)
eventvalidation_string = text1[eventvalstart:end_ind]

#getting "__VIEWSTATE" value:
viewstate_start_string= 'id="__VIEWSTATE" value="'
viewstate_start = text1.find(viewstate_start_string)+len(viewstate_start_string)
end_ind2 = text1.find('"',viewstate_start)
viewstate_string = text1[viewstate_start:end_ind2]

#POST request
payload = {"AC_xwTapCtl:AC_xwTapCtlCtl.xuWrqCtl:BillType":"PKT",
           "__EVENTTARGET":"",
           "__EVENTARGUMENT":"",
           "__LASTFOCUS":"",
           "__VIEWSTATE":viewstate_string,
           "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":"C0C9F6BC",
           "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED":"",
           "__EVENTVALIDATION":eventvalidation_string,
           "AC_xwTapCtl:AC_xwTapCtlCtl.xuWrqCtl:TagState":'VA',
           "AC_xwTapCtl:AC_xwTapCtlCtl.xuWrqCtl:TagNumber":'1234',
           "AC_xwTapCtl:AC_xwTapCtlCtl.xuWrqCtl:Next1":"Next >",
           "AC_xwTapCtl:scrollTop":'0',
           "AC_xwTapCtl:AC_xwTapCtlCtl.xuWrqCtl:Next2":"Next >",
           "AC_xwTapCtl:xwTap_txtFocus":"AC_xwTapCtl_AC_xwTapCtlCtl.xuWrqCtl_Next1",
           "AC_xwTapCtl_scrollTop":'0',
           "AC_xwTapCtl:AC_xwTapCtlCtl.xuWrqCtl:Next3":"Next >",
           "AC_xwTapCtl:xwTap_txtFocus":"AC_xwTapCtl_AC_xwTapCtlCtl.xuWrqCtl_Next2",
           "AC_xwTapCtl_scrollTop":"0"}

post = s.post(url, data=payload)
text = post.text
```

Thanks, -K.

Answer (score 2):

At this stage I'd probably switch to using beautifulsoup (pip install BeautifulSoup4) to parse the html to make it easier to get all the data out. Because it's .NET (I think) there's one form for the whole page so we could just grab out all the inputs.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get('https://capp.arlingtonva.us/tap/AC_xwTapPay.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

# grab out all the fields
payload = {i['name']:i.get('value') for i in soup.findAll('input')}
# populate the select field
payload['AC_xwTapCtl:AC_xwTapCtlCtl.xuWrqCtl:BillType'] = 'PKT'

# and submit the next step
r = s.post('https://capp.arlingtonva.us/tap/AC_xwTapPay.aspx', data=payload)    

# then parse / build next request etc
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
payload = {i['name']:i.get('value') for i in soup.findAll('input')}
payload['AC_xwTapCtl:AC_xwTapCtlCtl.xuWrqCtl:TagState'] = 'VA'
payload['AC_xwTapCtl:AC_xwTapCtlCtl.xuWrqCtl:TagNumber'] = 'blah'
r = s.post('https://capp.arlingtonva.us/tap/AC_xwTapPay.aspx', data=payload)    

# rinse and repeat as many times as required...
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```